# When the ancient one awakens, do we pass the first player token?

Tags: arkham-horror

Since the token passes at the end of the turn, and the awakening goes immediately to the awakening, do we skip passing the first player token for the first attack?

Comment: I cant find anything that mentions this - probably because it is not relevant. What is the actual issue you faced or is this just a hypothetical?

Comment: @link64 Some of the ancient ones care about who the first player is. If you're fighting [Zhar](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Zhar) you probably care who gets grabbed first. (Or you don't, because Zhar is incredibly hard to beat in combat.)

Comment: @link64 when one investigator can rely on the abilities or items of another, such as Mandy Thompson granting a re-roll to another player, the order in which players execute can affect how you choose to execute those abilities. A simple example with her is if A can roll 2 dice to attack but afterward B can roll 6, Mandy might choose to forgo letting A re-roll anticipating B may need it more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for The Final Battle (page 22 of the rulebook) state that the first player token should be passed at the start of the turn, when the investigators refresh:

> **1. Investigators Refresh**
>
> At the beginning of a round of combat with an Ancient One, the investigators may refresh their cards, use any character abilities, and adjust their skill sliders as though it were the Upkeep Phase. *Next, the first player marker should be passed to the left*. Finally, they may trade items among themselves as if they were in the same location (see “Trading Equipment” later in these rules).

(Emphasis mine)